# regular expression for some specific number

Tags: regex

I would like to validate the user input field to only allow user to input +1,-1,+10,-10 and +25,-25, nothing else. What is the regular expression for this restriction?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try with:

```
/^[-+](1|10|25)$/
```

It will allow one of your 6 possibilities.

Comment: You have to anchor the regex to not match -1000 for example

Comment: It works - checked. Provide some code in your answer so I'll check it.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't bother with a regexp. Presumably, you're going to ultimately need to parse the number from a String to an int, yes? In which case you could just immediately parse it and check the outcome is as expected, although this won't enforce the "+" sign if that's mandatory - but manually checking for the sign before parsing would be simple.

Answer (score 3):

If you're absolutely allowing only the specified inputs, and nothing else, then the following regex will do it:

```
/^[-+](1|10|25)$/
```

But what if someone enters "10" -- ie "+10", but without the plus sign? Is that allowed or not? You haven't specified. If it is, then the +/- needs to be optional, so the regex changes to this:

```
/^[-+]?(1|10|25)$/
```

Note that this regex also has start and end anchors (ie `^` and `$`), meaning that it won't allow any other characters in the string. Without them, it could match a string that contained "+20" in amongst other text.

Answer (score -3):

You don't specify a language the regex should be in, but this should work:

`[+-][12][05]?`

Comment: It allows also `+15`/`-15` and does not allow `+1`/`-1`

Comment: No, because it would allow "15" and "20".